# ical4j: add organizer who is able to cancel an event?

Tags: calendar, icalendar, ical4j

I am using ical4j to send out emails with a calendar attachment. I am able to add an organizer based on this SO post: [How should I use iCal4j to add a meeting organizer to an iCal event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35576698/how-should-i-use-ical4j-to-add-a-meeting-organizer-to-an-ical-event)

```
event.getProperties().add(new Organizer("mailto:bob@example.com"));
```

The problem is that no attendees added to the calendar is able to cancel an event. If I create (manually, no ical4j) an calendar appointment in Outlook Online, I am able to cancel an event as shown below:

[image]

However, the email with an ical4j attachment I received as the organizer (see the above code example) only gives me three options: Yes, No, Maybe as shown below:

[image]

How can I make someone among an meeting's attendees be able to cancel the meeting?

**------- Update 11/15 -------**
Based on the suggestion from @fortuna, my program generated the following event. I am still unable to cancel an event.

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Events Calendar//iCal4j 3.0.1//EN
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:REQUEST
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20211115T144506Z
DTSTART;TZID=America/New_York:20211215T110000
DTEND;TZID=America/New_York:20211215T114500
SUMMARY:ABC123 School
TZID:America/New_York
LOCATION:Virtual
UID:153ab747-bbd2-4964-9112-9fa0d29ed306
STATUS:CONFIRMED
ORGANIZER;ROLE=CHAIR:mailto:dev1@example.com
ATTENDEE;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT:mailto:dev2@example.com
ATTENDEE;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT:mailto:dev1@gmail.com
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

I manually generated an event in Outlook Online and forwarded it to my yahoo account to get the calendar attachment:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
METHOD:REQUEST
PRODID:Microsoft Exchange Server 2010
VERSION:2.0
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:Eastern Standard Time
BEGIN:STANDARD
DTSTART:16010101T020000
TZOFFSETFROM:-0400
TZOFFSETTO:-0500
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=1SU;BYMONTH=11
END:STANDARD
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
DTSTART:16010101T020000
TZOFFSETFROM:-0500
TZOFFSETTO:-0400
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=2SU;BYMONTH=3
END:DAYLIGHT
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VEVENT
ORGANIZER;CN="dev1":mailto:dev1@example.com
ATTENDEE;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;RSVP=TRUE;CN=dev2
 g:mailto:dev2@yahoo.com
ATTENDEE;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;RSVP=TRUE;CN="dev3"
 :mailto:dev3@example.com
DESCRIPTION;LANGUAGE=en-US:\n\n\n________________________________________\n
 From: dev1 <dev1@example.com>\nSent: Monday\, November 15\, 2021 8:5
 2:23 AM (UTC-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada)\nTo: dev3\; dev1\, 
 \nSubject: test\, please ignore it.\nWhen: Monday\, N
 ovember 22\, 2021 10:30 AM-11:00 AM.\nWhere:\n\ntest\n\n__________________
 ______________________________________________________________\nMicrosoft 
 Teams meeting\nJoin on your computer or mobile app\nClick here to join the
 .....
 cdd5fc5d11c&threadId=19_meeting_OGYzZjAdddxMjYtYYy00ZDE4LWE0NjctZjY4OTA0ZG
 I0ZTQ4@thread.v2&messageId=0&language=en-US>\n____________________________
 ____________________________________________________\n
UID:040000008200E00074C5B7101A82E00800000000933C540328DAD701000000000000000
 0100000001771BBC5CAD45B499CBF167EE077185B
SUMMARY;LANGUAGE=en-US:FW: another test for GRD\, please ignore it.
DTSTART;TZID=Eastern Standard Time:20211122T103000
DTEND;TZID=Eastern Standard Time:20211122T110000
CLASS:PUBLIC
PRIORITY:5
DTSTAMP:20211115T135223Z
TRANSP:OPAQUE
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SEQUENCE:0
LOCATION;LANGUAGE=en-US:
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-APPT-SEQUENCE:0
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-OWNERAPPTID:2119924365
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-BUSYSTATUS:TENTATIVE
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-INTENDEDSTATUS:BUSY
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-ALLDAYEVENT:FALSE
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-IMPORTANCE:1
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-INSTTYPE:0
X-MICROSOFT-ONLINEMEETINGINFORMATION:{"OnlineMeetingChannelId":null\,"Onlin
 eMeetingProvider":3}
X-MICROSOFT-ONLINEMEETINGTOLLNUMBER:+1 571-429-6038
X-MICROSOFT-ONLINEMEETINGCONFERENCEID:475654328
X-MICROSOFT-SKYPETEAMSMEETINGURL:https://teams.microsoft.com/l/meetup-join/
 19%3ameeting_OGYzZjAxMjYtYzFlYy00ZDE4LWE0NjctZjY4OTA0ZGI0ZTQ4%40thread.v2/
 0?context=%7b%22Tid%22%3a989b5e2ddda-14e4-4efe-93b7-8cdd5fc5d11c%22%2c%22O
 id%22%3a%2256f6a1be-b722-47fd-b69c-5950f281818f%22%7d
X-MICROSOFT-SCHEDULINGSERVICEUPDATEURL:https://api.scheduler.teams.microsof
 t.com/teams/989b5e2a-14e4-4efe-9ddd5fsasdfc5d11c/56f6a1be-b722-47fd-b69c-5
 950f281818f/19_meeting_OGYzZjddYtYzFl4Ysa00ZDE4LWE0NjctZjY4OTA0ZGI0ZTQ4@th
 read.v2/0
X-MICROSOFT-SKYPETEAMSPROPERTIES:{"cid":"19:meeting_OGYzZjAxMjYtYzFlYy00ZDE
 4LWE0NjctZjY4OTA0ZGI0ZTQ4@thread.v2"\,"rid":0\,"mid":0\,"uid":null\,"priva
 te":true\,"type":0}
X-MICROSOFT-ONLINEMEETINGCONFLINK:conf:sip:dev1@example.com\;gruu\;opaque=app:
 conf:focus:id:teams:2:0!19:meeting_OGYzZxAxMjYtdasYzFlYy00Z4LWE0NjctZjY4OTA
 0ZGI0ZTQ4-thread.v2!56f6a1beb72247fdb69c5818dasdfsadf!989b5e2a14e44efe93b78
 cdd5fc5d11c
X-MICROSOFT-DONOTFORWARDMEETING:FALSE
X-MICROSOFT-DISALLOW-COUNTER:FALSE
X-MICROSOFT-LOCATIONS:[]
BEGIN:VALARM
DESCRIPTION:REMINDER
TRIGGER;RELATED=START:-PT15M
ACTION:DISPLAY
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you may need to add something like a participation role to your organizer property:

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5545#section-3.2.16

e.g. ORGANIZER;ROLE=CHAIR:bob@example.com

Another way to find out how Outlook does it is to forward the event "as icalendar" to another email address and inspect the ".ics" attachment.

Comment: thanks so much for your help! I updated my post with the tests based on your suggestion.

Comment: Just to confirm, only the organizer should be able to cancel an event, other attendees won't have that ability. So when you test you should set the organizer to a real email address.

Comment: Yes, only the organizer should be able to cancel an event. The email addresses used in my tests are real email addresses.